# sending command to my Camera via usb port RAS PI (python)

Tags: python-2.7, camera, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to send command to my Flir camera TAU2 using USB and normally i should receive a respond from it, so what i'm doing first is that i'm configuring my serial port 
and then i'm sending my command via the serial port:
and then listening to the serial for a respond : 
this is a part of my code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.serCam = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate=9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=1,
        xonxoff=False
    )
def close_connection(self):
    if self.serCam.isOpen():
        self.serCam.close()

def serial_Read(self):
    while self.serCam.inWaiting():
        try:
            self.state=serCam.readline()
            return state
            print state
        except:
            pass
  def control(self):

    self.len= self.serCam.write(serial.to_bytes([0x6E,0x00,0x00,0x0B,
                                                 0x00,0x00,0x2F,0x4A,0x00,
                                                 0x00,0x00]))
    print ('commande envoye' )
    return len
```

i don't receive anything from my camera, do you have any idea please from where it can be ?

Comment: You either didn't show the complete code, or you are missing the definition of your Class `def ClassName` with 4 class methods. How do you execute the code? you should get several error messages with this code you shown.

Comment: Thank's first for responding, i didn't get any error with this code and yes i have a class camera that contain all of this methods, i'm calling my function on the main,

Comment: No error? at least you will get `len undefined` on the line `return len` because it should be `self.len`, isn't it? Post

Comment: it's really working :) but as you said it's better to change it because i'm using the len as local variable, and i found that my error was from my raspi and reading function i shouldn't use readline but just a simple read(number of  data). and  i don't know why but my raspi changes each time the number of USB port, so it's normal that we don't get anything from my USB0,so when i change all of this i got a respond from my camera: 6e00000b00020f0800022042. Sorry for my english mistakes